# SVG Sepia filter effect: mid-tones only

Tags: css, svg, photoshop, svg-filters

**Could you please help me finding out how can I achieve the Sepia tone on the link bellow using SVG?**

[My Sepia Tone made with Photoshop's Color Balance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5IZj.jpg)

I've tried the following code:

```
<svg class="defs-only">
  <filter id="monochrome" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
          x="0" y="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
      values="1.00 0 0 0  0 
              0.80 0 0 0  0  
              0.65 0 0 0  0 
                0  0 0 1  0" />
  </filter>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
img{
    -webkit-filter: url(#monochrome);
    filter:  url(#monochrome);
}
```

But the [feColorMatrix Sepia Tone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3imt.png) that I get is very different and appears not to be only affecting the mid tones as it does on Photoshop.

**Note: I can't use canvas.**

Comment: What UA are you using here?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome as a User Agent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well first of all, that's not a proper sepia filter. It's only using the red channel as input, so you're losing about a third of your luminosity off the bat. The "official" W3C sepia filter is:

```
   <feColorMatrix type="matrix"
  values="0.39 0.769 0.189 0  0 
          0.349 0.686 0.168 0  0  
          0.272 0.534 0.131 0  0 
            0  0 0 1  0" />
```

That gives you this result:

[image]

And if you just want to process the mid-tones then you need to pull the mid-tones out and process them separately. That looks like this:

```
<filter id="mid-sepia" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix type="luminanceToAlpha"/>
  <feComponentTransfer >
    <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 .2 0.5 1 1 1 0.5 .2 0"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
 <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
   <feColorMatrix type="matrix" result="sepia-clip"
  values="0.39 0.769 0.189 0  0 
          0.349 0.686 0.168 0  0  
          0.272 0.534 0.131 0  0 
            0  0 0 1  0" />

  <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix" result="gscale"
                values="0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 
                        0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 
                        0.2126 0.7152 0.0722 0 0 
                        0 0 0 1 0" />
  <feComposite operator="over" in="sepia-clip" in2="gscale"/>
</filter>
```

And gives you something that looks like this:

[image]

The magic here is the settings for feFuncA - which controls how wide the mid-tone selection is. "0 .2 0.5 1 1 1 0.5 .2 0" is a pretty wide selection - so if you want a narrower range given the sepia treatment, you might want to use something like "0 0 0 0.2 0.5 1 0.5 0.2 0 0 0" - play with it until you have something you like.

http://codepen.io/mullany/pen/rjdYre?editors=1000#

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you see this, but a feColorMatrix generator exists : https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/qJCDk

You just have to change the image by yours :

```
<image x="0" y="0" width="590" height="400" filter="url(#f1)" xlink:href="[YOUR IMAGE]"/>
```

You can play with all the parameters like in Photoshop.
Enjoy (ﾉ≧∀≦)ﾉ

Comment: The problem is that the color change made by feColorMatrix is applied to all tones...No just the mid tones like Photoshop as I stated inicially.

Comment: It's maybe due to the fact the web colors are limited.